# Repeat Annotation for TestNG at Spring

Tags: spring, testng

I've migrated to TestNG from Junit within my Spring application. However I could not see that how can I repeat my test methods with TestNG?

I decided to use Spring's annotation and extended my classes super class from:

```
AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
```

But, `@Repeat` annotation did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about invocationCount?  If it is the same test that you want to run let's say a fixed number of times, then you can specify a invocationCount on the @Test annotation.  Example [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests). You can even trigger in parallel.

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 10)
public void testMethod() {
```